# Alter a hidden input field when other fields are changed using jquery

Tags: jquery

When a user makes a change to the input field "vmake" i want a hidden input called "carsearch" to change its value from False to True.  The default value of the hidden input is False.  Here is my script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#vmake").change(function(){
       $("#carsearch").val('True');
    });
});
```

If its helful the HTML for the hidden input is:

```
<input id="carsearch" type="hidden" name="carsearch" value="False" />
```

Comment: You've already done that

Comment: my question is why isnt this working, am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe change that val="False" in your code into value="False"?
I don't know whether that matters at all but seems to me like the only error. Besides the missing ( after the $.

Comment: ok I fixed those 2 things, still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `val` as an attribute to your `input` element. It should be `value`.

#### Sample

```
<input id="carsearch" type="hidden" name="carsearch" value="False" />
<select id="vmake">
    <option>1</option>    
    <option>2</option>
</select>


$(function(){
    $("#vmake").change(function(){
        alert("Before = " +  $("#carsearch").val());
        $("#carsearch").val('True');
        alert("After = " + $("#carsearch").val());        
    });
});
```

### Check out this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8LtCb/3/)

Comment: No, in this case `.change()` is the right way. So only the `val` instead of `value` is the only problem. Check out my updated answer and the updated jsFiddle. Consider to accept if it solves your problem.

Comment: YESS! you helped my out so much.  Thanks a million for all that you guys do here in these forums, it is very very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an opening bracket:

```
$(function(){
    $("#vmake").change(function(){
        $("#carsearch").val('True');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input#vmake').change( function ()
    {
        $('input#carsearch').attr('val', 'True');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps :)